# INNO setup extract dir tree when setup starts prior to install

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an INNO setup program that works like a charm.  Now I need to add in a theme option pre-install for the user to select the theme for the application.  These themes are defined in a deployment directory that gets copied to the {tmp} folder on install.

What I am trying to do is look in this directory section for particular directories/files to determine the theme options.  When I find a theme, I will then add an option to a combo box for the user to select.  This selection will then affect the installation of the application (also from the {tmp} area).

My problem is that the files are not extracted to the {tmp} directory until the install button is clicked.  Is there a way to peek into the compressed file structure or force these files to the {tmp} directory prior to install?  The file structure is different for each of the themes and based on the customer only certain themes are available.

I have used the ExtractTemporaryFile method before, but I do not know what themes exist at runtime until the directory is extracted.  It would be nice to be able to extract an entire directory tree, but I am not finding an easy way to do this.

Thanks for your help.

The following is an example script of what I was originally trying to do:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\test
OutputDir=Output
OutputBaseFilename=tt
DisableReadyPage=false

[Files]
;;Source: readme.txt; DestDir: {tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme1; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion
;;Source: readme.txt; DestDir: {tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme2; Flags: ignoreversion     replacesameversion
;;Source: readme.txt; DestDir: {tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme3; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion
;;Source: readme.txt; DestDir: {tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme4; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion
Source: App\*.*; DestDir: {tmp}\App; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: readme.txt; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion

[Run]

[Code]

var
   curDir : String;
   TestPage : TWizardPage;
   ThemeComboBox: TNewComboBox;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
   TestPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, 'My test page', 'run test');

   // create the theme combo box
   ThemeComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(TestPage);
   ThemeComboBox.Name := 'themeselection';
   ThemeComboBox.Width := TestPage.SurfaceWidth;
   ThemeComboBox.Parent := TestPage.Surface;
   ThemeComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
   ThemeDir: String;
begin
   Result := True;

   if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
   begin
      // look for the networks and then add the ones that exist to the combo box
      ThemeDir := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\App\deploy\themes\tmeme1');
      MsgBox(ThemeDir, mbInformation, MB_OK);
      if DirExists(ThemeDir) then
      begin
         // populate the combo box
         // this is theme1 so it is Standard
         ThemeComboBox.Items.Add('Standard');
      end;

      ThemeDir := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme2');
      if DirExists(ThemeDir) then
      begin
         // populate the combo box
         ThemeComboBox.Items.Add('theme2');
      end;

      ThemeDir := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme3');
      if DirExists(ThemeDir) then
      begin
         // populate the combo box
         ThemeComboBox.Items.Add('theme3');
      end;

      ThemeDir := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\App\deploy\themes\theme4');
      if DirExists(ThemeDir) then
      begin
         // populate the combo box
         ThemeComboBox.Items.Add('theme4');
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is use ISPP to enumerate the files and build up the list of relevant entries at compile time that you can read at runtime.

This can either be output straight into a pascal array, or to a file that you then extract and read at runtime.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm not sure I know what you are talking about.  Thanks.

Comment: Steve, example added (quite late though :-) @Deanna, I don't think it is possible to output something from InnoSetup preprocessor to the runtime output (*output straight into a pascal array*). Constant arrays are not supported.

Comment: @TLama As you;ve demonstrated, it can output code to populate the array though :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite late, I know :-) Just to complete your question with the code sample; The following example fills the combo box with all folder names found on the path specified by the `SearchMask` variable. Every time it find a folder in that specified location, it adds a line to a string list. When the search through the location is done, the string list is assigned to the combo box:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: App\*.*; DestDir: {tmp}\App; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]
var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
  ThemeList: TStringList;
  ThemeComboBox: TNewComboBox;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Theme selection page', '');

  ThemeComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ThemeComboBox.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  ThemeComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  ThemeComboBox.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;  

  ThemeList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    #define SearchHandle
    #define SearchResult
    #define SearchMask "App\Deploy\Themes\*.*"
    #sub ProcessFoundFile
      #define FileName FindGetFileName(SearchHandle)
      #if (FileName != ".") && (FileName != "..")
        #emit '    ThemeList.Add(''' + FileName + ''');'
      #endif
    #endsub
    #for {SearchHandle = SearchResult = FindFirst(SearchMask, faDirectory); \
      SearchResult; SearchResult = FindNext(SearchHandle)} ProcessFoundFile
    #if SearchHandle
      #expr FindClose(SearchHandle)
    #endif
    ThemeComboBox.Items.Assign(ThemeList);
  finally
    ThemeList.Free;
  end;
end;

// you can save the current script file output after compilation preprocessing 
// to see the result
#expr SaveToFile("d:\OutputScript.iss")
```